# GWT TextArea placeholder don't works in IE 9

Tags: internet-explorer, gwt

I have a component textarea in GWT. The message of placeholder works in Google Chrome and Firefox, but I need a final test in IE 9, and the message don't work. There's another way for do this?

Thanks for attention.

Code:

```
myTextArea.getElement().setPropertyString("placeholder", "Final test in IE 9");
```

Comment: As a reference: [Browser support for `placeholder`](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_textarea_placeholder.asp).

Comment: The `placeholder` attribute of the `<textarea>` tag is not supported in `Internet Explorer 9` and earlier versions.